# Sub-divide the home screen iPad

Tags: ipad

I recently got hold of an iPad and was wondering if it is possible to have home screen dividers like if I want to label first row of the home-screen as email, second row as blog posts similar to

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. iOS will reorganize the apps and folders from the top left to bottom right automatically.

Reorganising your apps and folders on a per-page basis is the closest you can get: 1st page "Main", second page "Games", third page "iCrap", and so on.

Comment: tnx for the answer, can you suggest a way to add a title to each home screen, like you mentioned `Main`, `Games` etc

Comment: That's not possible either

Comment: tnx for your time @Vincent, @ patrix

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different, but you could also create folders for each of these categories. This gives you an area of the home screen that you can tap to open up each "container" like you have in the picture above.